# Model objects not being listed in Django template page?

Tags: python, django

I have a template page that iterates over the objects of my model and lists each one of them. My template is named user_page.html and here's the code that lists the items:

```
<h3>List of your games</h3>
{% if games %}
    <ul>
    {% for i in games %}
        <li>Game</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    You have no games.
{% endif %}
```

I keep getting the message 'You have no games' whenever I visit user_page.html but I know I have Game objects because I see them when I type Game.objects.all() in the console. So far, here are the codes I have on my views.py:

```
@login_required
def create_game(request):
    game = Game(creator=request.user)
    game.save()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'game': game,
        'board': game.get_set_board()
    })
    return render_to_response('battleship/create_game.html', variables)

@login_required
def list_games(request):
    games_list = Game.objects.get_by_user(request.user)
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'games': games_list
    })
    return render_to_response('battleship/user_page.html', variables)
```

And here is the code for my Game model:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator_set')
    def get_set_board(self):
        board = Board()
        return board
    def get_target_board(self):
        board = Board()
        return board
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure Game.objects.get_by_user(request.user) returns a non-empty queryset?

Comment: I'm not sure. I tried testing it with Game.objects.all() in my list_games function but even that did not work and I'm still getting "You have no games."

Answer (score 0):

Try returning your response like so:

```
return render_to_response('battleship/user_page.html', {'games' : games_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

See if that makes a difference.

Comment: I don't see how this would make a difference. What makes you suggest this? You're questioning a core django component, that if broken, would break thousands of people's implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Turns out the issue is the URLS.py mapping. Apparently, my user_page.html already had a function called user_page mapped to it. I just had to put the list_games function code inside the user_page function. Silly me. Thanks anyways everyone :)